# Warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c

```
int colision_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera,double x,double y,double h,double w)
{
    NodoPtr aux=cabecera->sig;

    while(aux->sig != NULL)
    {
        int colision=colision_bala(aux->b,x,y,h,w);

        if(colision)
        {
            NodoPtr borrar = aux->sig;
            aux->sig= borrar->sig;
            libera_bala(borrar->b);
            free(borrar);
            return 1;

        }
        else
        {
            aux=aux->sig;
            return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Al compilar me da este warning (control reaches end of non-void function)y no entiendo por que

Answer (score 1):

La alarma es clara y concisa, tal vez no la entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> control reaches end of non-void function

> el control alcanza el final de una función no-void

Viene a decir que la función no es `void`, es decir que la función devuelve algo:

```
int colision_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera,double x,double y,double h,double w)
^^^ <--- La función devuelve un entero (int).
```

Pero según los caminos que siga la ejecución de la función, acaba sin devolver (`return`) nada:

```
{
    NodoPtr aux=cabecera->sig;

    while(aux->sig != NULL)
    {
        int colision=colision_bala(aux->b,x,y,h,w);

        if(colision)
        {
            NodoPtr borrar = aux->sig;
            aux->sig= borrar->sig;
            libera_bala(borrar->b);
            free(borrar);
            return 1;

        }
        else
        {
            aux=aux->sig;
            return 0;

        }
    }

    // Aquí falta un return.
}
```

Si al entrar en la función `aux->sig` es `NULL`, el bucle no se ejecuta y acaba la función sin devolver nada.

Answer (score 1):

Te da el warning porque ambos return están dentro del `while` y el compilador no se va a dedicar a interpretar tus intenciones sino que analiza lo que hay. Y lo que hay es que si en la primera iteración `aux->sig == NULL` entonces el `while` no se ejecuta y, si no se ejecuta, tu función no tendrá `return`

Lo que sucede en tu código es que, tal y como está, el `while` sobra, ya que en la primera iteración se ejecutará o el `return 0` o el `return 1`.

```
int colision_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera,double x,double y,double h,double w)
{
    NodoPtr aux=cabecera->sig;

    int colision=colision_bala(aux->b,x,y,h,w);

    if(colision)
    {
        NodoPtr borrar = aux->sig;
        aux->sig= borrar->sig;
        libera_bala(borrar->b);
        free(borrar);
        return 1;

    }
    else
    {
        aux=aux->sig;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Pero claro, ahora no recorre la lista... lo que tienes que hacer es dejar el `return 0` fuera del bucle, ya que no debería abandonar la función hasta no haber recorrido toda la lista o encontrar el nodo buscado:

```
int colision_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera,double x,double y,double h,double w)
{
    NodoPtr aux=cabecera->sig;

    while(aux->sig != NULL)
    {
        int colision=colision_bala(aux->b,x,y,h,w);

        if(colision)
        {
            NodoPtr borrar = aux->sig;
            aux->sig= borrar->sig;
            libera_bala(borrar->b);
            free(borrar);
            return 1;

        }
        else
        {
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```